# How to cancel one SKaction if I have multiple SKactions

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm having difficulty removing 1 SKaction. I know that if I remove both SKactions with `removeAllActions()` but how do I go about only removing 1 will still having the other Action?

Comment: Run an action with a key. Remove the action for that key. search SO about this.

Comment: @Zulan The comment here sums it up exactly:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324393/you-have-made-too-many-incorrect-reviews-but-the-review-was-approved-overall#comment352009_324394

Answer (score 6):

You need to use runAction withKey:

```
yourNode.runAction(someAction, withKey: "key")

// and then sometime later...
yourNode.removeActionForKey("key")
```

Obviously it makes sense to define the keys somewhere a bit less flakey than as hard-coded key every time you use them...